# IE: element does not move when :hover makes another element visible

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, position, fieldset

I encountered a strange problem in IE 8/7 and I have gone through hell (and back) to reach a minimal test-case that demonstrates the issue...

Consider the following bit of HTML:

```
<form id="hover-test">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="hover">
       <p>always visible</p>
       <p class="hidden">Visble only on hover</p>
    </div>  
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <a href="#" id="link">Please jump</a>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this bit of CSS:

```
form                 { background-color:#f5f5f5; }
.hidden              { display:none; }
#hover:hover .hidden { display:block; }
#link                { position:relative; }
```

**What it should do:** On hover an additional paragraph becomes visible, pushing the next fieldset and all its contents down. (works fine in FF/Chrome/Safari/Opera)

**What it does in IE 7/8:** The paragraph becomes visible, pushing down the following fieldset. The link however stays fixed in place for reasons I can't fathom.

In the frustrating chase for a minimal mark-up that reproduces the problem (the effect vanished when I removed single lines of CSS from the original code, but my testcase could have them and still be fine... O_o) I identified at least three players working together here:

1. the fieldset: If I put everything in divs or in a form without fieldsets, all is well
2. the position:relative: Uncomment that line and voilá - link jumps.
3. the background color: This makes no sense whatsoever to me, but without this it works.

So, here's the question (apart from the implied "WTF?"):

Has anybody any clue on what is causing this behavior? And how to solve it? Or at least a hint into which of the many known IE issues I could look into to further test stuff?

Maybe I could come up with a way to bend the structure and...say... have the background-color on some additional wrapper div or something, but this seems... somewhat silly, and anyway, I feel as if not understanding this now will make things possibly very complicated down the road.

Comment: a paragraph should be `"display:block"`

Comment: thanks. Must have been a remnant from also testing with span/a instead of p. Edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was your comment about the `position: relative` that helped me solve it. That flagged me to think **`hasLayout`**! The issue seems resolved if you make sure both `form` and `fieldset` have layout set also (just giving it to the `#link` created the issue). One (among many) ways:

```css
form, fieldset {zoom: 1}
```

[**See the working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5yfNd/3/).

BTW: You should not have two `#hover` id's in your code. That should be set to a class (maybe it is just an error in your example, but I wanted to note it).

Comment: I actually tried hasLayout before, but either I put it on the wrong element or overlooked something or I don't know, but I ruled that out and didn't try again *sigh* Thanks for pointing me back to my old friend. Oh, and the double hover is a typing mistake.

Comment: @Louise--you may have overlooked that it needed to get set on _both_ the parent and grand-parent elements (`form` and `fieldset`); just putting it on one did not resolve it for me.